# Leak occur at the time of Parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I'm actually doing parsing at the start of my program and this is my parser.m class i found 
"leak" in this class in method "foundCharacters" in line

```
currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
```

currentElementValue is NSMutableString which is declare in parser.h file

```
NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
```

Can any one suggest me the way to solve this leak which some times crash my app in the starting...

### Thanks In Advance...

didStartElement Method:-

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"posts"]) {
        appDelegate.newsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else
    {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"page"])
        {

            aNewsInfo = [[NewsInfo alloc] init];
            aNewsInfo.page = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

        }


        if(![elementName compare:@"smallimage"])
        {
            currentElementValue = [NSMutableString string];

        }
        if(![elementName compare:@"largeimage"])
        {
            currentElementValue = [NSMutableString string];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Processing Element :%@",elementName);
}
```

Leak found in this foundCharacter method:- in line....

currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 
    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);
}
```

didEndElement method:-

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"posts"])
        return;
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"page"]) {
        [appDelegate.newsArray addObject:aNewsInfo];
        NSLog(@"%d",[appDelegate.newsArray count]);
        NSLog(@"%@",aNewsInfo.title);
        NSLog(@"%@",aNewsInfo.fulltext);
        [aNewsInfo release];
        aNewsInfo = nil;
    }
    else {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"smallimage"])
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentElementValue];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
            [aNewsInfo setSmallImageData:image];

        }
        if(![elementName compare:@"largeimage"])
        {
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:currentElementValue];
            NSData *data =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            [aNewsInfo setLargeImageData:image];
            [image release];
        }
        [aNewsInfo setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
        [currentElementValue release];
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to do some study:

Go to following links:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MemoryManagement

http://mattpatenaude.com/ch3-memory-management.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

then do this,

`currentElementValue = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease]`

and remove `[currentElementValue release]`, from

`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {`

 (otherwise it will leads to crash due to over releasing)

Comment: COrrect!!! Since initWithString in itself an autorelease method, so u  should not release it manually .....

or u can try this ::

currentElementValue = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
currentElementValue = [string copy];

Comment: can you also answer the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860576/how-to-remove-parsing-and-nsplaceholdermutablestring-frame-leaks-in-iphone. thanks in advance